# How many learnable parameters has a ridge regression classifier that has 20 inputs and 3 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

How many learnable parameters has a ridge regression classifier (this one: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV.html) if it is trained with input data that has a dimension of 20 (i.e. 20 features / attributes) and 3 classes / labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at `RidgeClassifierCV`, we can see that there is two type of learnable parameters:

- `coef_`: ndarray of shape `(n_targets, n_features)`
- `intercept_` : ndarray of shape `(n_targets,)`.

Therefore a dataset with 20 features and 3 classes will have `3*20 + 3 = 63` learnable parameters.

The code below can be used to compute the number of parameters of `RidgeClassifierCV`.

As follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifierCV

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=20, n_classes=3, n_informative=10)
model = RidgeClassifierCV().fit(X, y)

n_params = model.coef_.size + model.intercept_.size
```

Comment: Thank you Antoine Dubuis. I should have come up with this idea by myself. Too late yesterday. Thank you! Wish you a good life - you deserve it!